# How to use Linux like CONFIG_* configuration in my project?

Tags: c, linux, gcc, makefile, autotools

I'm currently writing a basic queue simulator program in C.

Source : https://github.com/iamsubhranil/DataStructure_C/tree/libqueue

I'm using the modular approach and wrote a library named libqueue(queue_library.c, header at queue_interface.h), and drew the user interface on top of that using queue_ll.c .

I've made a menuconfig like configuration using dialog, which will recompile the library (it doesn't as of now) based on the selected configurations by the user : For example, if the user wants to use only the functions of priority queue, the library will be recompiled containing only the functions of priority queue and so on.

I've cross compiled linux kernel for Android device and seen the rapid use of

```
make (codename)_defconfig
make -j(THREADS)
```

I want to use the following approach inspired by the Linux kernel :

```
#ifdef CONFIG_QUEUE_PRIORITY
priorityfunc1();
................
#endif
```

I'm learning to use autotools, but unable to find the process which will triggger `make` to use my configuration file and convert it into `#define` macros, like this :

```
make myconfig
make all
```

Obviously, the three options which `myconfig` should have :

```
CONFIG_LINEAR_QUEUE=y
# Based on user selection
CONFIG_QUEUE_DEQUE=y
# Based on user selection
CONFIG_QUEUE_PRIORITY=y
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is not achievable with autotools, because `autoconf` has its own handling of definitions based on `./configure` and `AC_CONFIG` macros.